# KDE Connect not connecting over OpenVPN

Tags: linux, android, openvpn

I am trying to get KDE Connect to work through my OpenVPN server I'm hosting at home, but I'm having a really weird problem. I'm running it in TUN mode which means broadcast packets won't work, which shouldn't be an issue as I should just be able to add my laptop via its IP and that should work fine (in fact, it did work when I was using my router as a VPN server, but now I am running it on a pi) The OpenVPN server has client-to-client enabled, and the really weird part is that wireshark on the laptop shows the packets from KDE Connect arriving to the laptop fine, but it just... doesn't respond. I've got no idea why. Phone is Android and the laptop has Linux Mint.

Edit: after some more investigation it would appear not all of the packets are being received by the laptop. There is a TLS Application Data packet that is also sent when the connection is properly established which is not being received when both clients are on the VPN. I've already tried shutting off the laptop's firewall briefly and that didn't work. This may have been a better question for server fault but I wasn't sure before if it was specifically a networking error or not...